# Swift: Split a long string into smaller strings when truncated (wrapped) around screen and goes to new line

Tags: ios, swift

How do I split a long string into three different strings every time it goes to the end of the screen and starts a new line.

**Note**: the string has no newline characters.
So basically as an example, I want to have 3 different strings from a single string because the string is long and goes to the end of the screen twice. Look at the image below.

The image below is what I currently have, it is one long string and I want to break it down into smaller 3 strings every time it wraps.

The code below gives you the number of times the long string wraps around the screen.

```
extension UILabel {
 func numberOfLines() -> Int {
    let maxSize = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(Float.infinity))
    let charSize = font.lineHeight
    let text = (self.text ?? "") as NSString
    let textSize = text.boundingRect(with: maxSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)
    let linesRoundedUp = Int(ceil(textSize.height/charSize))
    return linesRoundedUp
    }
}
```

Comment: Give `Top, Leading and Trailing` constraints to `UILabel`, and set `numberOfLines` as 0. No need of this extension for that.

Comment: @SharadChauhan please read the question.

Comment: Oh did I miss something ? Or you didn't understand what I am suggesting and what has been written as an answer ?

Comment: @SharadChauhan I have updated the question so its more clear

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly you want to wrap the long text.

You can do something like this to achieve the above:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

and if you want the label to adjust it font size to the available width you can do something like this:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Comment: I would also add constraints since it will be possibly attached to some view and that also affects; weather the label grows above 1 line or not. because It contains no anchors.

Comment: @eddwinpaz I don't think you understand my question. I want to break a long string into 3 small strings. I don't have an issue with wrapping. I have updated the question so its more clear

Comment: @Nate if that the case just create a UILabel extension .splitText() that you apply to your UI Label so basically you grab the string and by certain character length you add a \n \r but I think that UILabel it's not for you you should use a UITextview

Comment: @Nate and set label.numberOfLines = 3; label.splitText()

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you correctly, but you need to separate every line in label into separate string. I separate all the words by whitespace and recount numberOflines on each loop. Here is my code, sorry its messy, but I hope you will understand algorithm

```
    extension UILabel {

    func splitToLines() -> [String] {
        var array: [String] = []
        var words = text!.components(separatedBy: " ")
        var lines = numberOfLines(in: text)
        var currentLine = ""
        while lines != 0 {
            guard
                let firstWord = words.first
                else {
                    lines = 0
                    break
            }
            currentLine = currentLine.count == 0 ? firstWord : currentLine + " " + firstWord
            words.removeFirst()
            let currentNumber = numberOfLines(in: words.joined(separator: " "))
            if lines != currentNumber {
                lines = currentNumber
                currentLine = currentLine + " " + words.first!
                words.removeFirst()
                array.append(currentLine)
                currentLine = ""
            }
        }
        array.append(words.joined(separator: " "))
        return array
    }

    func numberOfLines(in string: String?) -> Int {
        let maxSize = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(Float.infinity))
        let charSize = font.lineHeight
        let text = (string ?? "") as NSString
        let textSize = text.boundingRect(with: maxSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font!], context: nil)
        let linesRoundedUp = Int(ceil(textSize.height / charSize))
        return linesRoundedUp
    }

}
```