# Swift: Split string given width of UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

How do I split a string given the width of UILabel.

```
str = "Here is a sample of a long string that wraps at the end of the screen three times." 

width = UIScreen.Main.Bounds.Width
```

**Expected Result**

```
strArray = ["Here is a sample of a long", "string that wraps at the  end", "of the screen three times."]
```

Look at image:

[image]

***The Goal is to extract the lines into strings, not wrapping.***

Comment: Is your goal just to wrap the text on the UI or extract the lines for other uses?

Comment: @RickyMo The goal is to extract the lines for other uses.

Comment: What do need it for? Maybe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I need it so when the UILabel is selected I can highlight each line with different colors. Importantly, I need spacing between the highlights so they don't touch each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Split a long string into smaller strings when truncated (wrapped) around screen and goes to new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57301855/swift-split-a-long-string-into-smaller-strings-when-truncated-wrapped-around)

Comment: Kindly don't ask the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> try below function

```
func getStringArrayFromLabel(in label: UILabel) -> [String] {

    /// An empty string's array
    var arrLines = [String]()

    guard let text = label.text, let font = label.font else {return arrLines}

    let rect = label.frame

    let myFont: CTFont = CTFontCreateWithName(font.fontName as CFString, font.pointSize, nil)
    let attStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    attStr.addAttribute(kCTFontAttributeName as NSAttributedString.Key, value: myFont, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attStr.length))

    let frameSetter: CTFramesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attStr as CFAttributedString)
    let path: CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
    path.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.size.width, height: 100000), transform: .identity)

    let frame: CTFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(frameSetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, nil)
    guard let lines = CTFrameGetLines(frame) as? [Any] else {return arrLines}

    for line in lines {
        let lineRef = line as! CTLine
        let lineRange: CFRange = CTLineGetStringRange(lineRef)
        let range = NSRange(location: lineRange.location, length: lineRange.length)
        let lineString: String = (text as NSString).substring(with: range)
        arrLines.append(lineString)
    }
    return arrLines
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this works as the device's screen changes? i.e different screen sizes iPhone 6, 6+

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help:

```
    let sampleFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    let oneLineHeight = NSString(string: "aaa").boundingRect(with: .init(width: 50, height: 10000), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : sampleFont], context: nil).height

    let estimatedHeight = NSString(string: "Here is a sample of a long string that wraps at the end of the screen three times.").boundingRect(with: .init(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 10000), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : sampleFont], context: nil).height

    let numOfLines = Int(estimatedHeight / oneLineHeight)
```